# Symfony2 Assetic Route and Resource Errors

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have template for example index.html.php where I use php assetic loader like this

```
<?php foreach ($view['assetic']->javascripts(
    array('@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*')) as $url): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $view->escape($url) ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I do any changes for my template file I get Route "_assetic_2b431f4" does not exist.

If I change

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

I get Cannot load resource ".". Error.

This comes when I do even one line change to file, so something about the cache. Clearing cache don't help etc. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go into routing_dev.yml and remove these lines:

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

Then everything should work.

This answer was also given here:

[How to make Symfony2 to load CSS, JS files directly and not via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258294/how-to-make-symfony2-to-load-css-js-files-directly-and-not-via-php)

**EDIT:** And if you haven't done so already, make sure you've done the whole

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

thing that's given in the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files