# Assetic generating links but no files

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm trying to use assetic in symfony2 to manage my css. 
The links are generated fine. However, no files are generated.

Here's my configuration:

**Layout.html.twig**

```
    {% stylesheets
      '@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
      filter='cssrewrite'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

**Config.yml**

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ FooBundle ]
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
```

**Config_dev.yml**

```
assetic:
use_controller: true
```

Assetic generates te link `foo.foo/app_dev.php/css/957d3aa_main_1.css`. However, the file isn't there (or anywhere else). I've tried playing around with permissions and looking in the (nginx) logs, but nothing so far.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have **2 options** when dealing with assets. The reason you do not see your assets physically in your computer is because you chose Option 1.

---

### **Option 1: SYMFONY CAN PROCESS THE FILES DYNAMICALLY FOR YOU**

That means that each asset path generated in the dev environment is handled dynamically by Symfony. Therefore, Assetic generates paths to CSS and JavaScript files that don't physically exist on your computer. This is an internal Symfony controller that opens the files and serves back the content for you.

***Advantages:*** 
    - Changes made on your assets take immediate effect
    - This is great in dev mode as Symfony generates the files dynamically for you

***Disadvantages:*** 
    - This is not possible in prod mode as rendering each asset dynamically would be too slow
    - The assets won't be directly accessible on your computer (which is why you cannot find the file)
    - Can be quite slow if you are using a lot of filters, etc...

To do this in dev mode, just edit assetic config in config_dev.yml:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

---

### **Option 2: DUMPING ASSET FILES**

If you don't want to handle the assets dynamically, you can dump your assets manually, meaning actually writing your assets phisically on your computer.

***Advantages:*** 
    - No need for Symfony to generate the files dynamically so this will run a lot faster
    - Therefore, this is perfect in prod mode
    - The files are physically accessible in the web/ directory (or wherever you chose to output them)

***Disadvantages:*** 
    - You either need to dump the assets each time you change something..or you can dump the assets with the --watch command, which can potentially be a bit annoying if you are working in dev mode.

To do this:

**Set use_controller to false (config_dev.yml):**

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
```

You can even choose where to read and output your assets if necessary

```
   assetic:
        read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/views/
        write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/thefolderyouwant/
```

The ouput now starts from your *write_to* config in assetic

```
{% stylesheets
  '@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
  output='css/main.css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

You will have a [resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861030/symfony2-assetic-route-and-resource-errors) if you continue, so comment out or delete these assetic route in config_dev.yml:

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

Finally, you can generate the assets automatically, so that the changes that you make take immediate effect:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --watch
```

In that case, the file should now be available:

*/web/thefolderyouwant/css/main.css*

See the Cookbook for more info: [How to use Assetic for Asset Management?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

Comment: I think it's better to edit your first answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: This works! File is now created. However, /app_dev.php/css/2c29233.css gives a 404; without app_dev.php it doesn't. I've tried every possible nginx config, but can't get it to work :( Gonna try a bit more. If I can't figure it out I'll post another question and put up a link here. Thanks eitherway! (p.s. Can't award the bounty for another 17 hours.. I will, no worries)

Comment: I'm really sorry but it turns out it doesn't work. It only works when dumping the assets first. It should work without.. That was the point :S

Comment: You definitely need to dump the assets as you set up use_controller: false in your config. Symfony is no longer generating these assets for you. You can add --watch when dumping the assets to add them automatically.

Comment: Also use_controller being on false, you don't go through the front controller app_dev.php. Therefore, Assetic does not add app_dev.php/ if you don't use it....which explains your 404 error.

Comment: That's why I have `use_controller` set to true in config_dev.yml. Even when I set it to true in config.yml, the files aren't being generated...

Comment: See my EDIT, your files aren't generated because this is what you chose to do (Option 1). Hope this helps.

Comment: Check the comment of June 7 15:51 -> Even when I set it to true, the files aren't being generated..

Comment: The link is also well created for me but the file is not **served** (nginx 404)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just needed to install java

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

you can also look on the begining of output, this might help:

```
app/console assetic:dump > outfile 2>&1
```

Comment: This is for Java based filters (YUI compressor) only.

Answer (score 0):

It also doesn't generate files when `use_controller: true` is on if you're using SASS to compile SCSS but `ruby` or the ruby gem `sass` not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error very similar to this one. Suddenly assetic stopped working. The only thing I added was the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle). Maybe you are using the rest bundle too.

Here is my solution:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json

    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true

    format_listener:
        rules:
            # render "/api" requests as json
            - { path: ^/api, priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
            # default, fallback rendering twig templates
            - { path: ^/, priorities: ['html', 'application/javascript', 'text/css', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```

I changed `priorities: ['html', '*/*']` to `priorities: ['html', 'application/javascript', 'text/css', '*/*']` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found solution !! I worked on this issue for hours! You wrote:

```
'@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' filter='cssrewrite'
```

BUT 'cssrewrite' filter doesn't accept @FooBundle syntax! You have to do:

```
php app/console assets:install
```

Symfony will create:

```
web/bundles/yourbundle/css/main.css
```

Now, in your twig template, replace:

```
'@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' filter='cssrewrite'
```

with:

```
'bundles/yourbundle/css/main.css' filter='cssrewrite'
```

Hope it's going to help someone else! (it's written in Symfony docs.. ^^)